# Android: button with custom layout and day/night themes

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Button with a custom layout and 2 themes (day and night).

The button layout has a background image (drawable) and a text (string).

The themes must differ in drawable (I have two PNGs) and text color.

My approach is as follows:

1. In the button layout set the background drawable as a selector:
2. this is the drawable/btn_basket_calls.xml

   ```
   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_basket_calls_pressed"
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:state_pressed="true"
       />

   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_basket_calls_pressed"
       android:state_focused="false"
       android:state_pressed="true"
       />

   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_basket_calls_selected"
       android:state_focused="true"
       />

   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_basket_calls_disabled"
       android:state_enabled="false"
       />

   <item
       android:drawable="?attr/btn_basket_calls_default"
       android:state_focused="false"
       android:state_pressed="false"
       />
   ```
3. the "default" drawable is a reference to the attribute "btn_basket_calls_default" which is defined in attrs.xml as follows:
4. The AppTheme has two subthemes in styles.xml:

   @drawable/btn_basket_calls_d_default

   @drawable/btn_basket_calls_n_default

AFAIK it should work :) however the project complies fine but gives a runtime exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.daynighttest/a.daynighttest.DayNightTestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at a.daynighttest.DayNightTestActivity.onCreate(DayNightTestActivity.java:13)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/btn_basket_calls.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020000
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:120)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    ... 25 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #31: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1154):    ... 30 more
```

See attached complete Eclipse project for details.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have to add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

to beginning and this:

```
</selector>
```

to end of btn_basket_calls.xml file.